# Why is my Rails app not pushing to Github? (error:1407742E:SSL )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, ssl-certificate

I am finishing off a blog tutorial and am trying to do my final push to GitHub and Heroku. I just added the popper gem to the `Gemfile` and then tried to push to GitHub as usual using `git push origin master`.

Normally it then asks for my username and password, but instead I got the following error and have no idea what it means or why I got it. I haven't changed anything else as far as I remember.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/<username>/FrogBlog.git/': error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I am unsure how to proceed, as this message means nothing to me. I can post more files from my project if required, please advise.

Comment: Check this if it help https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/git-clone-fails-with-ssl-routines-ssl23_get_server_hello-779171759.html

Comment: thanks but this article doesnt seem to be relevant since it talks about a solution for bitbucket and i am pushing to github. also the solution there is for Ubuntu i am using windows 10, i am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Related, see GitHub's [Weak cryptographic standards removal notice](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/). Maybe it will be easier to switch from `https://` to `git://`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitHub recently [deprecated some old and insecure cryptographic standards](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/), including TLSv1, which is referenced in your error message:

> On **February 8, 2018** we’ll start disabling the following:
>
> - TLSv1/TLSv1.1: This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web, API, and git connections to https://github.com and https://api.github.com.
> - diffie-hellman-group1-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com
>     diffie-hellman-group14-sha1: This applies to all SSH connections to github.com
>
> We’ll disable the algorithms in two stages:
>
> - **February 8, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST)**: Disable deprecated algorithms for one hour
> - **February 22, 2018 19:00 UTC (11:00 am PST)**: Permanently disable deprecated algorithms

Most Git clients should continue to work, but there are some [known incompatibilities](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/#known-incompatible-clients).

If you update your Git client (it looks like you're using the standard CLI client?) pushing to GitHub will probably start working again.

Comment: i'm sure this must be the problem. i have opened the desktop github client and it is up to date (i think it updates when you open it). i am still getting the same error though. is there another component that i need to update or do something else to my Github account?

Comment: @Owen, are you trying to push using the GitHub Desktop "sync" button or something else? Your question says you're running `git push origin master`.

Comment: yes i am using the command line. i have the github app on my computer but never use it. i dont know how. i thought that you meant to update that. what should i be updating and how exactly? i dont really understand what my error means. i have a very vague understanding of ssl if that

Comment: @Owen, your command-line Git might be too old. What does `git --version` give?

Comment: git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2

Comment: @Owen, it looks like support for TLS1.2 might have been [added in Git version 2.6.0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/01861cb7a27b948bc0218877311f531f25386691), which was [released in September, 2015](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.6.0). I recommend updating Git to the [latest version](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.6.0), which at the time of writing is 2.16.2.

Comment: i have downloaded the zip file that you recommend, however it is just a folder with hundreds of files in it. what do i do with them?

Comment: @Owen, sorry, I linked to the wrong thing. That last link was supposed to be the [the download link for Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Comment: so i downloaded it and have been able to push, it seems.  However, i tried to do the push through the command line and i still get the same error. so what is happening? do i need to also update something else in order to be able to push via the command line.

Comment: i updated but by command prompt is still saying it is the old version version:    git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2 how do i update the command prompt part? i never use the other way with the GUI.

Comment: @Owen, have you restarted your terminal?

Comment: @Owen, how did you install Git in the first place?

Comment: really i dont remember it was about 1 year ago that i did it.  but what you have told me to download is very different from what i have on my machine. I have never used or seen this Github GUI software before. i have only every used the ''command prompt with ruby and rails''. i was trying to update that. are they 2 separate things?

Comment: @Owen, I haven't pointed you to any GitHub GUI. Didn't you have that on your machine already? The software I linked you to is the standard Git CLI for Windows.

Comment: It looks like you [might have used railsinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464198/where-did-command-prompt-with-ruby-on-rails-come-from-and-why-does-it-keep-cre)? The railsinstaller site appears to be down, but [it looks like the latest version includes Git 2.7.0](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt). If railsinstaller sounds familiar consider installing [the latest release](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/releases) and see if that works. The Git it bundles is old, but should include the new TLS code.

Comment: yes, i believe i used rails installer. If i update will this also update my rails version. i have v 5.0.6 so will this cause any problems for projects i am currently making. for example a tutorial i am following which uses rails 5 something, but not the newest version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165832/discussion-between-chris-and-owen).

Comment: git version 1.9.4.msysgit.2 - is latest version? returned error  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version