# Connection to github does not work after OpenSSL upgrade

Tags: github, openssl

We have upgraded OpenSSL from 0.9.8 to 1.0.2n (7 Dec 2017). We need support for TLS 1.2.

Downloading from git repositories worked before, but now we get on most commands, such as:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

> ```
> Permission denied (publickey).
> ```

Or when using composer, it fails when downloading from repositories:

Loading composer repositories with package information

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]   The "[repository_url_here]"
>   file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages:   error:1407742E:SSL
>   routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version   Failed
>   to enable crypto   failed to open stream: operation failed

Do I have to generate new private / public keys, or to reconfigure github? Php has SSL support enabled, just checked it.

Comment: Related, see GitHub's [Weak cryptographic standards removal notice](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/). Maybe it will be easier to switch from `https://` to `git://`.

Comment: I cannot believe, after years, we decide to upgrade OpenSSL yesterday, and on the same day github removes support for TLSv1/TLSv1.1.

Comment: It sounds like you are on OS X due to OpenSSL 0.9.8. Unfortunately, OpenSSL 0.9.8 is ***not*** binary compatible with OpenSSL 1.0.2. You will need to rebuild everything that wants to use the new OpenSSL, and that probably includes Composer. It may explain the SSH error as well, but the SSH error you show is usually related to a server config setting.

Comment: No, it is a Linux system. Previously it had OpenSSL 0.9.8 installed, now we upgraded it to 1.0.2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my Rails app not pushing to Github? (error:1407742E:SSL )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947351/why-is-my-rails-app-not-pushing-to-github-error1407742essl)

Comment: OpenSSL upgrade will not affect SSH (they are completely independent) for your first issue.  That SSLv2/3 handshake that Composer is attempting has numerous well-known security issues.  There should be a later version that at least requires TLS.

Answer (score 0):

if you have mac os version 10.10 (yoshimite) 
1. check openssl(use command line - **openssl version** -), if you have openssl version 0.9. or lower, you must upgarde to version 1.2 or higher. you can install homebrew and upgarde openssl with home-brew.
2. check php version( use command line **php -v**, if your php version 5.6 or lower. you must upgrade your php.